# Use of distinct() in dropdownlistFor

Tags: model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

I am trying to use distinct() in my dropdownlistFor in order to get rid of duplicates.
Model.Categories contains a list of strings.
Been trying different "combinations" but cant get it to work..I thought the below example would do the tric but it still shows duplicates.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CatDropTemp,
                                                Model.Categories.Select(kat => new SelectListItem { Text = kat, Value = kat }).Distinct())
```

Do I maybe have to change the whole construction of the list or is there something im missing?

EDIT:

Found this syntax here at the forum:

```
 @Html.DropDownList(
                "Foo",
                 new SelectList(
                 Model.Categories.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }).Distinct(),
                 "Value",
                 "Text"
               )
             )
```

That takes care of the Distinct()-part, however...With this syntax I cant see where I add my

```
new{@class="form-control"}
```

Any tips on that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do your distinct earlier in the chain, it doesn't look like SelectListItem implements any Equality/Comparison interfaces (assuming your model overrides Equals and GetHashCode)